# Fuzzy search in the elasticsearch gives matches with incorrect order

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to build an engine where we can match areas mentioned in the address with the list available in elasticsearch.

I am using this query to search areas similar to "iit".

My query is :

```
{
   "query": {
      "fuzzy": {
         "locality": {
            "value": "iit",
            "fuzziness": 1
         }
      }
   },
   "highlight": {
      "fields": {
         "locality": {}
      }
   }
}
```

I am getting below results :

```
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 2.1290483,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "geocoding_1",
            "_type": "localities",
            "_id": "AVuzRiZ04pEQsZFpK6A_",
            "_score": 2.1290483,
            "_source": {
               "locality": [
                  "emerald isle ii"
               ]
            },
            "highlight": {
               "locality": [
                  "emerald isle <em>ii</em>"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "geocoding_1",
            "_type": "localities",
            "_id": "AVuzRfof4pEQsZFpK59H",
            "_score": 1.877402,
            "_source": {
               "locality": [
                  "iit - bombay",
                  "iitb",
                  "indian institute of technology - bombay"
               ]
            },
            "highlight": {
               "locality": [
                  "<em>iit</em> - bombay",
                  "<em>iitb</em>"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Because "iit" is directly available in the 2nd document and hence I was expecting that to be returned as best match with highest score. What is the change that I should make so that I get 2nd document with highest score.

I am using ES 2.3.4 .

Answer (score 2):

If  you also are interested in exact matching to score better, I always suggest a `bool` with `should` statements and adding a `match` or `term` query in there. In this way the combined scores will favor the exact matching:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "locality": {
              "value": "iit",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "locality": "iit"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "locality": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh thats nice. I did not know of combined score. Essentially I can add up more and more sub query in the should array to get best result